# MATLAB - Newtons Method but error message "Singular Matrix"

Tags: matlab, matrix, runtime-error, newtons-method

When I use newtons method to find the roots of a system of equations I get the following error message:

> "Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND =  1.625479e-33. > In new (line 16)"

Any ideas why I get this error message? I know about singular matrices and the inverse thing but could this really have to do anything with that? If so, how? What difference can I make to the code? It says line 16, which is `dx = -J\f;`. But I just follow along with my numerical methods textbook. Something must be wrong, but the exercise says "use Newtons Method" so I guess this should work. I hope someone can help me.

```
x = [0 0 pi/2]';
maxiter = 10;
iter = 0;
dxnorm = 1;
results = cell(maxiter + 1, 2); % Preallocate results array

while dxnorm > 0.5e-4 && iter <= maxiter
    f = [cos(x(1)) + cos(x(2))    + cos(x(3))-2; ...
         sin(x(1)) + sin(x(2))    + sin(x(3)); ...
         tan(x(1)) - 2.*tan(x(2)) + tan(x(3)); ...
         ];
    J = [-sin(x(1)),       -sin(x(2)),          -sin(x(3)); ...
         cos(x(1)),        cos(x(2)),           cos(x(3)); ...
         tan(x(1)).^2 + 1, -2*tan(x(2)).^2 - 2, tan(x(3)).^2 + 1 ...
         ];
    dx = -J\f;
    results{iter + 1, 1} = x;
    x = x + dx;
    dxnorm = norm(dx,inf);
    results{iter + 1, 2} = dxnorm;
    iter = iter + 1;
end
x, iter
```

Comment: Its probably because the derivative is close to zero, and Newtons method fails in those cases. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Derivative_issues

Comment: What you should do, is find bad cases, and there, just use other method, i.e. Bisection method. So when `J~=0` then use other method.

Comment: Is this method doomed to fail in this case then?

Comment: The way you wrote it, yes. J\f is syntax sugar for inv(J)*f. If J now becomes singular then inv(J) doesn't exist, thus the error. You can try `pinv(J-lambda*eye(size(J)))` where lambda is some relaxation parameter instead.

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger Not really. `J\f` solfes `Ax=b` problem with the rigth choice of algorithm.

Comment: Is the problem ill posed? tan(x(3)) appears in f and J; x(3)=pi/2 to start; tan(pi/2)=Inf

Comment: To give Ander's comment more insight, MATLAB has a variety of algorithms to solve for the inverse of a system, depending on how the the coefficient matrix `A` is shaped.  It also goes through a variety of checks and gives you a warning should the matrix `A` be singular - meaning that the inverse solution provided by the matrix `A` is very sensitive to floating point changes in the coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial conditions of `x(3) = pi/2` leads the 3rd entry of `f` to become infinite because `tan(pi/2) = sin(pi/2)/cos(pi/2) = inf`, except it's *not* quite infinity because of floating point imprecision, imprecision in `pi` etc... so instead you just get an insanely large number.

Now you have insanely large numbers along with insanely small numbers, and everything basically gets !@#$ed. Your Jacobian matrix is badly scaled etc...

The linear equation which blows up is:

```
[0,    0,   -1                                       [x1      [0
 1,    1,    0                                    *   x2   =   1
 1,   -2,   266709378811357100000000000000000 ]       x3]      16331239353195370]
```

These are !@#$ed up conditions for numerically solving a linear system.

#### what should you do?

Start somewhere sane. Eg. start from initial conditions `[0,0,pi/4]` and everything might work fine.

Some initial conditions also trigger the multivariate equivalent of the derivative being zero (which will also make Newton's method blow up).

Comment: hahahaha `!@#$`ed up conditions. Thanks for the laugh today. +1.